# find and copy usage using wildcards

Tags: find, wildcards, file-copy

I'm looking to copy a specific folder inside an other one, but I don't have the exact names, for example

```
/volume1/User/save/01/**-**** ?/GROUPES **-****/
```

`**-****` is a number reference that changes everytime but always formated the same (eg : 75-1234) and `?` are words (Lion Tiger Shark) --> `/75-1234 Lion Tiger/` Shark)

And I want to copy `/GROUPES **-****/` to `/volume1/User/01/`

My last try was

```
find /volume1/User/save/01/**-**** ?/ -iname "GROUPES **-*****" -exec cp -r /volume1/User/save/01/
```

And it's (obviously?) not working.

Comment: Asterisk stands for any number of characters, ? stands for one character, see http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm

cp takes SOURCE, then DESTINATION (https://linux.die.net/man/1/cp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jonas noted, you need a `?` to match one character and a `*` to match multiple characters. A space character needs to be escaped with a `\`.

With the first pattern `**-**** ?` changed to `??-????\ *` and the escaped space characters, the command should be:

```
cp -r /volume1/User/save/01/??-????\ */GROUPES\ ??-????/ /volume1/User/save/01/
```

Comment: worked like a charm thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

copy does the following:

```
cp SOURCE DESTINATION
```

We want to copy the directories (meaning we use -r or recursive) from groupes to another folder so we do: (you must use ? as wildcard, not *, because asterisk stands for multiple characters, so will allow everything with an asterisk)

```
cp -r /full/path/to/GROUPES' '??-????/ /volume1/User/save/01/
```

You don't need to give wildcards for the destination directory, because you are copying to within the folder of 01, and you're not changing the name

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what about the folder before /GROUPES ??-????/ that changes everytime ? `cp -r /full/path/to/??-???? namethatchangesverytime/GROUPES ??-????/ /volume1/User/save/01/`

Comment: @Jonas you need to escape the space so that the shell doesn't try to split the filename into multiple parts. Either quote it (`' '`) or prefix it with backslash (`\ `). This then gives `cp -r /full/path/to/GROUPES\ ??-????/ /volume1/User/save/01/`. But I think you're missing a wildcard match for the name part (`Lion Tiger`, etc.)

Comment: @roaima Thanks!